# New React project 2.1 fails with NPM ERR! 418 I'm a teapot

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, visual-studio-2017

I have latest Visual Studio 2017 with node v10.4.1, npm  v6.1.0.
I can create ASP.NET Core 2.0 React project and NPM dependencies load OK and I can launch the newly created project in a web browser.

However when I create a new ASP.NET Core 2.1 React project, restore of NPM packages fails with:

```
NPM: ERR! 418 I'm a teapot: acorn@5.3.0
```

What could be wrong if NPM clearly works well in 2.0 project, but 2.1 NPM restore fails with that silly foolsday error.

.npmrc looks like this:

```
proxy=http://xxx.xxx.cz:3128/
registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
strict-ssl=false
```

A command executed from cmd.exe:

```
cd %ProgramFiles%\nodejs
npm install npm@latest
```

ends also with

```
npm ERR! 418 I'm a teapot: npm@latest
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have also encountered this error for another type of project, on a server that relies on a proxy. I have managed to make it work by using `https` instead of `http` for the registry:

```
 registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Answer (score 2):

Hm, not sure, whether I should delete this post. It is connected with the [issue described here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/20791#issuecomment-392648459), but should have been fixed a month ago. Apparently anything that goes wrong with proxy servers produces the silly `418 I'm a teapot` error. I have removed the line with our proxy server

```
proxy=http://xxx.xxx.cz:3128/
```

from the `.npmrc` config file (in the Users folder), so there remained only

```
registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
strict-ssl=false
```

Now everything went OK and React project with ASP.NET Core 2.1 launches without error.

I admit that the silly error message does not seem funny any longer.

Comment: Yes, this definitely related to proxy settings. The proxy servers seem to work fine (the browser is using them), but if I remove them from the `.npmrc` file, downloading is impossible (npm cannot connect directly to the Internet). How could you download the packages without any proxy servers settings?

Comment: @Alexei I do not know, I got simply badly stuck with nodejs this way but knowing it works for another project. So I experimented, perhaps our proxy can behave as a transparent proxy now.

Comment: Then you are lucky not to require proxy settings.

Comment: that issue in Github was so unhelpful: "we resolved the issue"

Comment: @KansaiRobot The fix apparently did not include changing the error message to something more reasonable.

Comment: I find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51524828/how-do-i-solve-the-npm-418-im-a-teapot-error-when-trying-to-use-npm-install more useful

Comment: @KansaiRobot Ok, but mark that the linked question was asked later than this one, so the asker could have been aware already that the problem was connected with the proxy settings.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error in my project and the main reason is change in our proxy settings. So i would like to suggest to check your proxy settings ... few commands which i used to resolve this error...

```
npm set strict-ssl false 
 npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

//additional commands if Npm is behind a corporate web proxy
`npm config set https-proxy http://...:8080` `(add server proxy address and your port number)`

```
npm config set http-proxy http://...:8080 (add server proxy address and your port number)
```

Comment: So you suggest switching to https and checking if the proxy configuration is still valid? So your solution was similar to @Alexei ?

Answer (score 0):

npm set strict-ssl false

npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/

Comment: Thanks, what is the difference compared to previous answers?