# How do I solve the NPM "418 I'm a teapot" error when trying to use npm install?

Tags: node.js, npm, proxy

I've been trying to install Yeoman and Gulp on a server that has a corporate proxy using the following command:

```
npm install -g yo gulp
```

However when I run this comand (or any "npm install" command) I get hit with:

```
npm ERR!       E418
npm ERR! 418 I'm a teapot: gulp@latest
```

I'm pretty confident that this is an issue pertaining to the proxy but I can't figure out what exactly is causing it.

Some tests I've done:

- I added the proxy to my npmrc file with login information for authentication and I believe it's entered properly. If I change any part of the username or password my error changes to an E407 (authentication failed).
- I ran "npm config set strict-ssl false" and that seemed to not do anything.
- I tried running different installs and I still just get "418 I'm a teapot *package*@latest".

Answer (score 37):

So after a few more hours of digging through forums and blogs the solution was to change my registry from "http://registry.npmjs.org/" to "https://registry.npmjs.org/".

Apparently when on some proxies the registry will redirect to the address but add port 443 to the address if trying to connect without the https.

Hope this helps anyone else experiencing this issue!

Comment: Yes, thanks! that was my problem too.  I had an old .npmrc pointing to http instead of https.

Comment: Thank you for restoring my sanity

Comment: Excellent. You saved my day!!

Answer (score 21):

I also got this error in my project and the main reason is change in our proxy settings. So i would like to suggest to check your proxy settings ... few commands which i used to resolve this error...

```
npm set strict-ssl false 
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

> check=  https://registry.npmjs.org/

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for answering now my npm not showing **Err 418 i'm a teapot again**.

**You must update npm config like this :**

```
npm set strict-ssl false 
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Try again install package using `npm..`

Answer (score 4):

After visiting many sites and testing everything i found,
This Solution finally worked for me. If you are using Windows,

1. Click windows button and type "run"
2. Type `.npmrc` and open this file using your favorite editor.
3. Replace registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/ with registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/ and save.

**Note:** If you have any proxy issues too..you can set your proxy like below in the same file. In my case i have a **special symbol "@"** in my password.
When i tried changing proxy using **npm config set proxy** command these special characters got converted to something else :) So you could eliminate all these headaches if you set your proxy along in this file directly.

Your final `.npmrc` should look like below. you could remove proxy lines if you do not have any issues with proxy and do not forget to replace the port in below example with your proxy port.

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/  
proxy=http://username:password@yourproxy.net:8080/  
https-proxy=http://username:password@yourproxy.net:8080/  
strict-ssl=false
```

Answer (score 1):

change registry from `http://registry.npmjs.org/` to `https://registry.npmjs.org/` using below command:

`npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`

Answer (score 0):

Npm team sent this statement for the issue-"At peak, the 418 responses were 0.01% of traffic. npm has a great many users (over 10M), so given traffic over the time of the incident that works out to between 500 and 1000 actual users affected. Obviously, even one user bitten by a bug is more than we'd like, but relative to our scale it was not a major issue. The specific proxy configuration necessary to trigger the bug is relatively rare, so even among users behind proxies most people were not affected. Once we were alerted to the bug in our header parsing, the ops team quickly deployed the fix."

So, surely the people behind the proxy are affected as I faced the same issue. So, solution here is-

Check proxy- npm get proxy and npm get https-proxy
if both are set to none, please set it to-

npm set proxy http://proxyAddr:8000
npm set https-proxy https://proxyAddr:8000

then try again.

If the issue still persists check the registry for npm-

npm get registry
if http://registry.npmjs.org/ then,

change it to npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/ (This should fix the issue, for me it worked).

Answer (score 0):

When you are behind a corporate firewall at then you get this issue, to resolve this I have followed the following steps:

```
npm set strict-ssl false 
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

If you are behind corporate proxy then you can use the following command as well:
`npm config set https-proxy http://IP:PORT/`

Or Directly go to your .npmrc file and point to https instead of http.